# Why are some Siebel objects read only?

Tags: project, readonly, siebel

I want to add some extensions to an existing Siebel application, but the objects which I need to change remain (partially) read only, despite I have locked the respective parent projects. 
E.g.

- Add a Menu item to the application main menu. => I can edit existing items, but I cannot add new items (Tool's menu "New record" is disabled.)
- Add a custom applet to view "Sales Home Page View". It's read only (Warning displayed by Tools when I click "Edit web layout").

Any ideas, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Siebel Tools. After a restart of Tools I was able to perform the desired changes.